# How do I apply styles to different `TextBlock` objects?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Here is my Application `ResourceDictionary`

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CABI_PO_Manager.Themes">   
 
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>


    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
           TargetType="TextBlock"
           x:Key="YellowTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#d8b243"/>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
           TargetType="TextBlock"
           x:Key="GreenTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
    </Style>

    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
           TargetType="TextBlock"
           x:Key="RedTextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#a01e21"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I want to have some default styles for a `TextBlock` which works

```
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
```

I found somewhere to use `x:Key` but I can't get it to work.

I will have several `TextBlock`'s, How do I identify a `TextBlock` in the UI XAML as Red, Yellow or Green `TextBlock` and apply that style to them? This isn't recognized `x:Key="GreenTextBlock"`

```
<TextBlock x:Key="GreenTextBlock"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="PO Manager" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center" FontWeight="ExtraBold"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u want apply style on for example all TextBlocks in application, just use style without x:key defined e.g

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Comic Sans MS"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    </Style>
```

When you are applying a style, use `TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"` instead of TargetType="TextBlock"

When do you use want to base on other style use

BasedOn="{StaticResource StyleUWantToBaseOn}"

where StyleUWantToBaseOn is style with x:Key property

And when you want to apply a specific style on lets say textblock you want to use Style property e.g:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource GreenTextBlock}" Grid.Column="1" />
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. That was the ticket! Thanks for the help.